# Can quicklook view .coffeescript files on Mavericks

Tags: macos, coffeescript, osx-mavericks, quicklook

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this but does anyone know if it's possible to get quick look working nicely for .coffee files on OS X (Mavericks)? It's kinda doing my head in at the moment!

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### One-liner:

```
curl -O https://gist.github.com/pavel-sakun/6192519/raw/090206d38e09207a56a69c93947f48ede122d75c/QLTextFiles.sh | sh
```

> Gist source available at https://gist.github.com/pavel-sakun/6192519.

Found at: https://coderwall.com/p/dlithw

Checked this on my 10.9 Mac and works fine.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Michal - I had to do it following the  https://coderwall.com/p/dlithw rather than the shell script for some reason, but in any case it worked :) :) :)